# How does the Boolean return value in this JavaScript work?

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to programming and have been working hard to teach myself. I came across the following problem online and tried to solve it, but hit a dead end:

> "Write a function that accepts three arguments and returns true if only one of those arguments is truthy, and false if not. Do not use && or || operators or if statements."

This stumped me for the past two days, so I moved on to the solution, which I'm having trouble figuring out:

```
function onlyOne(x, y, z) {
    return (!!x + !!y + !!z === 1);
}
```

I understand the syntax, but I don't understand the logic or why this works. Would someone be able to help me out? I want to learn why the code works, and not just memorize syntax.

Comment: The addition operator treats the boolean values as integers, `0` for `false`, `1` for `true`. `!!` is a way to convert just about any value to its boolean equivalent

Comment: FYI, this sort of boolean comparison is called an *"exclusive OR"* or `XOR` if you're interested in doing some more research.

Comment: `!!` = "bang bang you're a Boolean"

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that `!!` isn't a special operator but just two repeated `!`. The first one converts the argument to a Boolean and inverts the result, and the second one inverts it again to arrive back at the original object's truthiness value.

Answer (score 4):

`!!` casts the value to an actual boolean. When you perform addition on boolean values, JavaScript coerces them into number, `false` being `0` and `true` being `1`.

Basically, `(!!x + !!y + !!z === 1)` casts `x`, `y`, and `z` to `true` or `false`, then adds them all together. If only 1 of them is truthy, the value will be `1`, and `=== 1` will be true, else it will be false.

Here is an example showing how addition with booleans works:

```js
console.log(false + false); // 0
console.log(false + true);  // 1
console.log(true + true);   // 2
```

Answer (score 1):

`!!` "casts" your variable into a boolean which can only has the value `0` or `1` when casted back into a number via the `+` operator. If you think about it, you can only get `1` after adding them together if only one variable is true.

Comment: *"which can only has the value 0 or 1"* <- this isn't quite accurate. The boolean primitives `true` and `false` are type-cast to integers `1` and `0` by using them in a mathematical expression